# SciFi and Fantasy Moderator Business Cards

Tags: discussion

A long long time ago, we printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place.

If you're a scifi.stackexchange moderator, would you be interested in having your own Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out to your fellow scifi & fantasy fans during local meetups or conventions.

Below is a mockup:

(click on image to see full res version)

[image: scifi.stackexchange.com moderator cards]

Of course Twitter ID/email/phone are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL, etc.

<sub>Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.</sub>

Comment: This is a nice idea.

Comment: I've been to many conventions and tons of people there have had fandom-related business cards made up to give away -- they're extremely popular and useful. It allows fans (or, in this case, our mods) share their affiliation with the site, but to control what information is made public and available. Just a thought, but it might be nice to include the mod's user icon on a card too, as people come to know each other at the site by user icon, at a glance. I could see the user icon fitting nicely in the lower right corner on the back of the card. I think the cards are a good idea.

Comment: Who would say no to this? Now I only need to become a moderator!

Comment: @Slytherincess One hazard of including the gravatar on the card is that it kind of locks the person in to a single gravatar, lest their account no longer match what's on the card. Granted, the screen name could change, too, but I think people (moderators, at least) are less likely to change their screen name than their gravatar.

Comment: @Slytherincess: It could be a nice option:-)

Comment: @Slytherincess Here's a discussion on your point: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/58525/what-is-more-memorable-avatar-or-username

Comment: I'm guessing this is no longer a thing? :-)

Answer (score 17):

I am in favor of this.

I like the design.

Answer (score 15):

Thank you, I deserve this.

Comment: -1 for *Futurama* ... ;)